# Why when I'm adding a contextmenu items to pictureBox it's deleting drawn rectangle?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In the form1 constructor I did:

```
ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
cm.MenuItems.Add("Save Rectangle");
cm.MenuItems.Add("Reset Rectangle");
cm.MenuItems.Add("View Rectangle Information");
pictureBoxSnap.ContextMenu = cm;
```

Then I draw some rectangle on the pictureBoxSnap then if I'm doing right click mouse on the pictureBox I see the menu items but then the rectangle I drawed is deleted. How can I make that the rectangle will stay ?

This is the paint event:

```
private void pictureBoxSnap_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{            
    if (pictureBoxSnap.Image != null)
    {
        if (ClearGraphics == false)
        {                       
            if (rectangles[listBoxSnap.SelectedIndex] != Rectangle.Empty)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Firebrick, rectangles[listBoxSnap.SelectedIndex]);
            }                       
        }
        if (cropRect == true)
        {
            if (recttest.Width > 10 && recttest.Height > 10)
            {
                pnt = PointToScreen(pictureBoxSnap.Location);
                e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);
                e.Graphics.CopyFromScreen(pnt.X + rect.X, pnt.Y + rect.Y, rect.X, rect.Y, new Size(rect.Width, rect.Height));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you set the picturebox.image?or clear it in any way?

Comment: I see now that in the first time i make right click it's ok i see the menu and the rectangle is stay but if i make another right click this time i see the menu but it's deleting the rectangle.